# Rotation about non-principal axis (moment of inertia)

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, torque, moment-of-inertia

I have been told that an object rotating about the principal axis must have its angular velocity parallel to its angular momentum.

My question is: what would an object whose angular velocity is not parallel to its angular momentum look like? (is there an animation that demonstrates this?). How does it differ from rotating about a principal axis where the angular velocity is parallel to angular momentum? Can you tell just by looking at the motion whether an object is rotating about its principal axis or not?

Also, how can you tell that a symmetric object must have its principal axis on the line of symmetry?

The only clue that I am able to find is that if torque is applied to an object rotating about a non-principal axis, then the object will not accelerate in the direction of the torque. But this is about angular acceleration rather than angular velocity and I cannot visualise angular acceleration as well as angular velocity.

Comment: https://solarviews.com/cap/ast/toutspin.htm

Comment: Does that mean the axis of rotation will keep changing?

Comment: Yes. While we associate angular momentum to rotation, its definition $L = \sum r_i \times p_i$ is far more general. It is possible a complicated movement keeping $L$ unchanged.